# 変数に格納されている HTML 文字列から div タグを削除する

Tags: php, html

DBからHTMLを文字列として取り出し、divタグを抜いた形でupdateしたいと考えております。
phpによる一連の流れとしては、以下のような形になります。

```
$DB_html = "元の形のhtml"
$get_html= $DB_html;

// なんらかの処理で$get_htmlに格納されているhtmlのdivタグを削除
// $get_htmlをDBにUPDATE
```

以下のようなHTMLでdivのタグだけを全て削除したいと考えています。

**元のhtml:**

```
<div class="article_content">
<div class="article_image_text">
<p class="article_text">テキストテキスト</p>
テキストテキスト
</div>
</div>
<div class="article_content">
<h2 class="article_headline" style="border-bottom-color: #0096CC;">テキストテキスト</h2>
</div>
<div class="article_content" data-item-type="Image">
<div class="article_image_area clearfix">
<div class="article_image"><img class="article_img x-article-image " src="" />
<p class="rel">テキストテキスト<a href="" target="_blank">テキストテキスト</a></p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="article_content">
<div class="article_image_text">
<p class="article_text">テキストテキスト</p>
テキストテキスト
</div>
</div>
```

**divタグを削除したhtml:**

```
<p class="article_text">テキストテキスト</p>
テキストテキスト
<h2 class="article_headline" style="border-bottom-color: #0096CC;">テキストテキスト</h2>
<img class="article_img x-article-image " src="" />
<p class="rel">テキストテキスト<a href="" target="_blank">テキストテキスト</a></p>
<p class="article_text">テキストテキスト</p>
テキストテキスト
```

どのようにすれば実現できますでしょうか。
詳しい方、ご教示下さい。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: ソース（例えばajaxで返されたHTMLテキストをjavascriptで処理するとかHTMLテキストをPHPで事前処理するとか）の処理ではなくて、DOMの処理としてですか？

Comment: 削除するならテキストエディタで出来ますが、質問の意図はそうではないでしょう。残念ながら質問の文章を読んだだけではあなたが何を実現したいのか読み取れません。SOのヘルプには質問する際のガイドラインが幾つか書かれていますのでぜひ一度ご覧になって、質問を「編集」してください。SOでは質問の「編集」が推奨されています。そうすればエキスパートの方が回答を付けてくれると思いますよ！

Comment: PHP の内容と判断し、タグなどを変更しました。間違っていたらロールバックして下さい。

Answer (score -1):

下記のソースコードはご要望に合っておりますか。
ご確認お願いいたします。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   string = $("body").html();
   string = string.replace(/<\/div>/g, "");
   while (string.indexOf("<div") >= 0) {
    divstagstartindex = string.indexOf("<div");
    divstagendindex = string.indexOf(">", divstagstartindex);
    divtag = string.substring(divstagstartindex, divstagendindex + 1);
    string = string.replace(divtag, "");
   }
   
   alert(string);
   
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="article_content">
<div class="article_image_text">
<p class="article_text">テキストテキスト</p>
テキストテキスト
</div>
</div>
<div class="article_content">
<h2 class="article_headline" style="border-bottom-color: #0096CC;">テキストテキスト</h2>
</div>
<div class="article_content" data-item-type="Image">
<div class="article_image_area clearfix">
<div class="article_image"><img class="article_img x-article-image " src="" />
<p class="rel">テキストテキスト<a href="" target="_blank">テキストテキスト</a></p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="article_content">
<div class="article_image_text">
<p class="article_text">テキストテキスト</p>
テキストテキスト
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```